# How to escape a new line in api so it does not add "n" in the iPhone application

Tags: php, ios, json, api

Here is the part of the code which outputs the data in the api:

```
$message = str_replace('"','&#34;',$message); 

$message = utf8_encode($message);

$info = array('whosendit' => $use_id,
         'message_number' => $message_number,
         'date' => $date,
         'seen' => $checked_mess,
         'message' => $message,  
         'pic' => $pic
    );
    $rows[] = $info;        
}

$row66 = array($rows, $other_side_avatar, $other_side_name, $other_side_sex, $banned_or_not, $blocked, $start_position);

echo str_replace("\\","", json_encode($row66));


exit;
```

What happens here is that the str_replace is removing the \ in front of \n and for this reason if a message is "How are you(new line here)" the application will display "How are youn" instead of a new empty line after the sentence. I need the str_replace to do what it does because without it links like uploads/mypicture.jpg will be returned as uploads/mypicture.jpg which we can not use in the app. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: `uploads/mypicture.jpg` is using a forward slash, why are you stripping backslashes? (also why does the forward slash break your app)

Comment: If I do not strip backslashes json will escape forward slash and I need the actual image representation which would be uploads/mypicture.jpg and not uploads\/mypicture.jpg so the app is being able to load this picture otherwise it is not an actual path to open. Lets forget about the picture for a second and imagine that the line echo str_replace("\\","", json_encode($row66)); is a constant so we do not think about it. What we need to think about is how to make the new line work.

Comment: How stupid is that? Sounds like you just do not properly decode the data in your app. Check your data transport and that you encapsulated it properly, so far it's broken (or more likely even in-existent on the ios side)

Comment: @hakre probably as stupid as you are but you have just being dealing with these kind of issues longer. I will check it. Thank you for your advice but I do not appreciate neither the language nor your downvote so you can leave now. No help from you needed here even if you are Zuckerberg himself.

Comment: In PHP you do the json_encode operation. It works. No need to apply changes on the return value of it. Just pass it along. On the other side decode the json string. Done. Just meant that encoding something but then not decoding it is just the work half done.

Comment: And calling me Zuckerberg is far worse than calling me stupid. You're crossing a line here! :)

Comment: :D but you do have a sense of humour I give you that :P I see your point there. Thank you. I will definitely try it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to replace. Just return encoded array.

For example you are getting on front-end this json:

```
{"name":"Some name","image":"\/uploads\/some_dir\/lol.jpg"}
```

try to use it in browser console:

```
var str = {"name":"Some name","image":"\/uploads\/some_dir\/lol.jpg"};
console.log(str);
console.log(str.image)
```

you'll get normal data:
[image]

so you could decode json in app and use image url.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the solution would be on the app side as well I just did not know I need to decode it there. I will try it shortly.

Comment: @WhogivesAshit no problem) Just check it as answered if it will help you)